# Rails and mysql use different DB while using the same connection string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mariadb

I used to have mySQL installed in my Rails app and everything was good until I had to install MariaDB (because Sphinx is not compatible with mysql 8).

After deleting the database and recreating it, my I getting this:

```
rails db:create
Database 'xxx_dev' already exists
Database 'db/test.sqlite3' already exists
```

but if I start mysql I get this:

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 12
Server version: 10.3.13-MariaDB Homebrew
.....

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
```

My Rails app connects to the db using sockets. Apparently, they are not using the same MySql instance (I brew uninstalled everything but MariaDB).

Comment: I see SQLite mentioned in the error message.  Are you using that database as well?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Rails can use multiple databases for each environment. The tests are run in sqlite. You can skip that part.

Comment: Can you post your `config/database.yml` file?